# Using Group By on a non numeric field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a table like this:

```
 ID   |   Name  |  Age 
 1    |   Bill  |  30
 2    |   Jim   |  20
 3    |   Bill  |  30
 4    |   Bill  |  30 
 5    |   Bob   |  25
```

I want to return this:

```
ID   |   Name  |  Age
1    |   Bill  |  30
2    |   Jim   |  20
5    |   Bob   |  25
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 SELECT ID,Max(Name),Age FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY ID,Age
```

What do I got to do?

Comment: There is no Bob with ID 3, so how could it possibly work?

Comment: What you want to achieve by `Max(Name)`?

Comment: So you want a distinct age per name, but with your own `ID` added? There's no relation between ID=3 and Bob.

Comment: @hvd fixed.  @wojtek look at `what i want to return`  @michael: fixed.

Comment: With your edit it makes a bit more sense, but still, what makes `1 | Bill | 30` a better result than `3 | Bill | 30`?

Comment: It could be any of them, I just need one name.

Comment: Can't you use `DISTINCT` then?

Comment: @Wojtek, then i wont have ID in the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
select MIN(ID), NAME, AGE from TABLE group by NAME, AGE
```

Comment: I was about to answer almost the same way, except I would also have used `MIN(AGE)` and removed it from the `GROUP BY`. Assuming -- and that's a big assumption -- that a name only exists with a single age, both queries would return the same data.

Answer (score -2):

Grouping by ID has no sense, because ID is already unique.

```
SELECT Max(Name), AGE
   FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY Age
```

Comment: He wants distinct values with any ID from matching rows. So this is actually not a good answer.